# Basic Authentication With Curl Multi

Tags: php, curl

I'm using the below curl multi function to query an array of urls. It works great however I need to use basic authentication to access the data. Usually I would authenticate through sending the following header:

```
$headers = array();
$headers[] = "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode("$username:$password");
$opts = array(
  'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"GET",
'header' => $headers:
```

however I cant work out how to integrate this in my curl multi function, can anyone help?

```
<?php

function multiRequest($data, $options = array()) {

  // array of curl handles
  $curly = array();
  // data to be returned
  $result = array();

  // multi handle
  $mh = curl_multi_init();

  // loop through $data and create curl handles
  // then add them to the multi-handle
  foreach ($data as $id => $d) {

    $curly[$id] = curl_init();

    $url = (is_array($d) && !empty($d['url'])) ? $d['url'] : $d;
    curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_URL,            $url);
    curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_HEADER,         0);
    curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    // post?
    if (is_array($d)) {
      if (!empty($d['post'])) {
        curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_POST,       1);
        curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $d['post']);
      }
    }

    // extra options?
    if (!empty($options)) {
      curl_setopt_array($curly[$id], $options);
    }

    curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $curly[$id]);
  }

  // execute the handles
  $running = null;
  do {
    curl_multi_exec($mh, $running);
  } while($running > 0);


  // get content and remove handles
  foreach($curly as $id => $c) {


    $result[$id] = curl_multi_getcontent($c);
    curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $c);
  }

  // all done
  curl_multi_close($mh);

  return $result;


}

?>



<?php

$data = array(
'https://xxxxxyyyyyzzzzz.json',
'https://xxxxxyyyyyzzzzz.json',
'https://xxxxxyyyyyzzzzz.json',
'https://xxxxxyyyyyzzzzz.json',
'https://xxxxxyyyyyzzzzz.json',
'https://xxxxxyyyyyzzzzz.json',
'https://xxxxxyyyyyzzzzz.json',
'https://xxxxxyyyyyzzzzz.json',
'https://xxxxxyyyyyzzzzz.json',
);
$r = multiRequest($data);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($r);

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add:

```
curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_USERPWD, "username:password");
```

... to the list of libcurl options you set. [CURLOPT_USERPWD](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_USERPWD.html) is the generic user+password option but it will trigger HTTP Basic auth by default.